# Ensure define is processed when recompiling

Tags: c++, eigen, precompile

I am working on a c++ project using Eigen.
Recently I added a function to Eigen MatrixBase using the recommended way described here:

https://eigen.tuxfamily.org/dox/TopicCustomizingEigen.html

This web page explains how to add a new eigen function in a new file called MatrixBaseAddons.h. Then it asks to define EIGEN_MATRIXBASE_PLUGIN

> Then one can add the following declaration in the config.h or whatever prerequisites header file of his project:
>
> #define EIGEN_MATRIXBASE_PLUGIN "MatrixBaseAddons.h"

This is the part that bothers me... I didn't create the project I am working on and am new to CMake. I don't see a config.h file in our project and don't know where to add the definition above to ensure that EIGEN_MATRIXBASE_PLUGIN is always defined.

In a c++ project using CMake, how can we see / change the order in which the files are compiled? Where should I put this line

```
#define EIGEN_MATRIXBASE_PLUGIN "MatrixBaseAddons.h"
```

to ensure that it is always defined?

Comment: Sounds like the key phrase is "Whatever prerequisites header file of his project".

Comment: Just wondering *why* they should prefer this approach over inheritance...

Comment: Apparently, the MatrixBase supports lots of different types and functionalities and I suppose that one could possibly break something by overriding the base class. I don't know if you had a look at the link in my question: The doc clearly specifies: `Before inheriting from Matrix, be really, i mean REALLY sure that using EIGEN_MATRIX_PLUGIN is not what you really want` So I went for the first option

Answer (score 1, accepted):

try adding the following line in your CMakeLists :

```
add_definitions(-DEIGEN_MATRIXBASE_PLUGIN="MatrixBaseAddons.h")
```

this will add your definitions to your compiler command line. More info in [CMake add_definitions page](https://cmake.org/cmake/help/v3.1/command/add_definitions.html#add-definitions)